# $\bigcap_{B\in\emptyset}B=A$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose $\beta(A)$ is the power set of A and $\Omega\in\beta(A)$.

$\bigcap_{B\in\emptyset} B=\{x\in A: x\in B$ for all $B\in\Omega\}$

And the book said $\bigcap_{B\in\emptyset}B=A$

While I understand:

1. vacuously true

It is also written in the book "Elementary Set Theory" and I quote:

"By the axiom of extension, if A is a set and $P(x)$ is a statement function, then $\{x\in A:P(x)\}$ doesn't constitute a set if $P(x)$ is true for every object x.

So, why does $\bigcap_{B\in\emptyset}B=A$?

Comment: Are you confusing $\emptyset$ and $\Omega$ somewhere? Also, why does $\beta(A)$ only appear once in your question?

Comment: I am sorry. I have forgotten to include a relation between $\Omega$ and $\beta(A)$.

Comment: In fact, this is one of my confusions when reading the text too. If the target is an empty set, why bother to bring up $\Omega$. But I guess the implication is that by specifying $\Omega\in\beta(A)$, it could be dependent on the set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this becomes clearer when you view the intersection as the set-theoretic analogue to taking infima in ordered sets. Indeed $\bigcap_i B_i$ really is the infimum of $\{B_i \mid i\}$ in the poset $(\mathscr{P}(A),\subseteq)$. Now ask yourself: What is the infimum of the empty set? It must be the greatest element of the poset, if such a thing exists, and the infimum doesn't exists otherwise.

So why is $\bigcap_{B\in\emptyset} B = A$? Because you view this within the context of subsets of $A$, i.e. you work inside the poset $\mathscr{P}(A)$ and $A$ is the greatest element of this poset. When you switch contexts and work with *all* sets ordered by inclusion, then $\bigcap_{B\in\emptyset} B$ exists if and only if your set theory allows for a greatest set, i.e. a set of all sets. The most common axioms for set theory do *not* allow for a beast so that $\bigcap_{B\in\emptyset} B$ does not exist.

So the question really is: Do your work with subsets of a fixed superset or do you work with arbitrary sets?

Comment: It would have to be a set *containing* all sets (as subsets), not a set *of all sets* (as elements).

Comment: Right, so it would be $P(V)$, not $V$ itself.

Comment: No, more like $\bigcup V$, if $V$ is the sets of all sets. I think you made it worse ;-)

Comment: But $\bigcup V = V$ because $V$ has all the singletons as elements (unless the set theory has atoms). So my original claim was correct.

Comment: So could I say, intuitively, $\bigcap_{B\in\Omega} B = A$, where $\Omega\subset\mathscr{P}(A)$ is an operation finding the maximum subset of $A$. Since I view it in the context of $A$'s subsets, which gives me at most $A$. 
However, say I simply say a set of all set, that's a no since there is a counter example regarding to the claim there isn't a set of all set(subset).
My question, however, is should I just treat this as an intuition as well as definition?

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is that an operation on nothing gives the identity of that operation.  For instance the sum over no numbers is $0$, but the product over no numbers is $1$. This is a nice way to define these since it allows for taking the sum (or product) with one more number to be the previous sum (or product) with the number.

In the case of set intersection, the identity is the universal set, $U$, since $U\cap B = B$ for any $B \subseteq U$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's yet another way to justify this definition:

Note that if $\mathcal S$ is a non-empty set of subsets of $A$, we have
$$\bigcap_{B\in\mathcal S}B = \bigcap_{B\in\mathcal S\cup\{A\}}B$$
as can be easily verified (because intersecting a subset of $A$ with $A$ obviously results in the subset itself).

Now you would not want to make an exception for $\mathcal S=\emptyset$, therefore you get
$$\bigcap_{B\in\emptyset}B = \bigcap_{B\in\emptyset\cup\{A\}}B= \bigcap_{B\in\{A\}}B = A$$

Note however that this is crucially dependent on the assumption that you deal only with subsets of $A$, and that this definition depends on your choice of $A$. That is, while for non-empty $\mathcal S$ the definition of $\bigcup_{B\in\mathcal S}B$ is universal, the extension to $\mathcal S=\emptyset$ leads to a *different* operation depending on what you choose the full set to be.

Since in the commonly used set theory (known as ZFC) there is no set of all sets, it is not possible to define the empty intersection universally (at least not in a way such that all desired properties hold).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So could I say this is actually kind of another definition? I should accept it and understand it intuitively?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what exactly you mean with “another” here. It is a definition, but it is not an arbitrary definition; it's the definition that gives as many desired properties as possible. If you want to get a deeper understanding on why it is defined this way, you can try to come up with other definitions and check which desired properties they do or don't provide.